# NAudio WasapiLoopbackCapture ComException (0x88890003)

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio, wasapi

I am trying to use the WasapiLoopbackCapture class (NAudio 1.7.1.17) and ending up with the COMException (0x88890003). The recording format is `WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2)`. I have multiple playback devices on my system and have tried setting each one as the default device with the same results. I have also verified that each of those devices has `(44100, 16, 2)` listed as a supported format.

**Console Output:**

```
WasapiCapture_RecordingStopped.

Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x88890003): Exception from HRESULT: 0x88890003
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioClient.get_AudioCaptureClient()
   at NAudio.CoreAudioApi.WasapiCapture.DoRecording(AudioClient client)
   at NAudio.CoreAudioApi.WasapiCapture.CaptureThread(AudioClient client)
```

**Code:**

```
public static class Program
{
    private static int Index = 0;
    private static int TotalBytesRecorded = 0;
    private static bool RecordingStopped = false;

    private static void Main (string [] args)
    {
        var device = NAudio.Wave.WasapiLoopbackCapture.GetDefaultLoopbackCaptureDevice();

        using (var capture = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.WasapiCapture(device))
        {
            capture.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2);
            capture.ShareMode = NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioClientShareMode.Shared;
            capture.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(Program.WasapiCapture_DataAvailable);
            capture.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.StoppedEventArgs>(Program.WasapiCapture_RecordingStopped);

            Program.Index = 0;
            Program.TotalBytesRecorded = 0;
            Program.RecordingStopped = false;

            capture.StartRecording();
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            capture.StopRecording();

            while (!Program.RecordingStopped)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("TotalBytesRecorded: {0}.", Program.TotalBytesRecorded.ToString("N0"));
    }

    private static void WasapiCapture_DataAvailable (object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        Program.Index++;
        Program.TotalBytesRecorded += e.BytesRecorded;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write
        (
            "Index: {0}, BytesRecorded: {1}, Buffer Length: {2}, TotalBytesRecorded: {3}.",
            Program.Index.ToString("N0").PadLeft(10, ' '),
            e.BytesRecorded.ToString("N0").PadLeft(10, ' '),
            e.Buffer.Length.ToString("N0").PadLeft(10, ' '),
            Program.TotalBytesRecorded.ToString("N0").PadLeft(10, ' ')
        );
    }

    private static void WasapiCapture_RecordingStopped (object sender, NAudio.Wave.StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        Program.RecordingStopped = true;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("WasapiCapture_RecordingStopped.");

        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Exception: {0}", e.Exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Just google the error code.  Good hit [is here](https://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/246592).

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks. I had already searched and found three discussions including the one you linked to. Unfortunately, everything in there checks out except for Mark's suggestion of taking it up in the WASAPI forums. Since I needed some simple capture/streaming functionality for a project, have shifted to Bass.NET (still using WASAPI) for now.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I am using part of your code but my `DataAvailable` event is not being raised when I am playing audio from my default device. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Ibrahim: It is impossible to tell without seeing the actual code. You could create a minimal version and post it to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the capture for WASAPI loopback capture - you have to use the system mix format, which will use 32 bit floating point samples. Just use the `WasapiLoopbackCapture` class directly and it will work.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! I changed the `using` statement to `using (var capture = new NAudio.Wave.WasapiLoopbackCapture(device))` and it gave me much more sensible exception `WaveFormat cannot be set for WASAPI Loopback Capture`. Commenting that line out worked.